# Как разместить текст справа от изображений

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

У меня не получается разместить текст так, что бы он был справа от изображений во всех блоках

Пробовал через `float`, но не работает

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;700&display=swap');

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

ul {
    padding-left: 0px;
    display: flex;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 35px;
}

.menu {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 28px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.header {
    display: flex;
}

.container {
    
    width: 1170px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.logo {
    width: 179px;
    height: 41px;
    margin-top: 28px
}

/* Интро */

.intro {
    display: block;
  padding-bottom: 120px;
    background-image: url(https://netology-code.github.io/html-2-diploma/sources/images/banner-bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
  margin-bottom: 64px;
}

.title {
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 45px;
  padding-left: 200px;
  padding-right: 200px;
  
}

.date {
  opacity: 50%;
}

.author {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.img {
 display: block;
 width: 381px;
}

.tag {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #b59f5b;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-right: 19px;
}

.block {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 59px;
  width: 778px;
  
}

.block-title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.text {
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Контейнер --->
<div class="intro">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Хэдер -->
        <header>
            <div class="header">
                <div class="logo">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="https://netology-code.github.io/html-2-diploma/sources/images/noemi-logo.svg">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <nav class="menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Главная</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Посты</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Статьи</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Теги</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Темы</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Контакты</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="title">
                <h3>Блог о творчестве, спорте, и образе жизни</h3>
            </div>  
        </header>
    </div>
</div>
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <article class="block">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="https://netology-code.github.io/html-2-diploma/sources/images/last-post1.jpg" alt="10 мест, ради которых стоит
  проснуться на рассвете">
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <div class="tags">
          <span class="tag">Health</span>
          <span class="tag">Travel</span>
        </div>
        <div class="block-title">
          <h1>10 мест, ради которых стоит проснуться на рассвете</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="date">
          <span>10 июня 2019</span>
        </div>
        <div class="author">
          <span>Неизвестный автор</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text-d">
          <p>Итак, вы в Питере. Раннее утро. Лед с рек и каналов уже ушел, запущены фонтаны города… Музеи еще закрыты. Что посмотреть?</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article class="block">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="https://netology-code.github.io/html-2-diploma/sources/images/last-post2.jpg" alt="10 мест, ради которых стоит
  проснуться на рассвете">
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <div class="tags">
          <span class="tag">Health</span>
          <span class="tag">Lifestyle</span>
        </div>
        <div class="block-title">
          <h1>ЙОга для начинающих в домашних условиях</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="date">
          <span>10 июня 2019</span>
        </div>
        <div class="author">
          <span>Неизвестный автор</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text-d">
          <p>Расскажем, какие упражнения выбрать и как сделать коврик для занятий йогой из того, что можно найти в шкафу.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article class="block">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="https://netology-code.github.io/html-2-diploma/sources/images/last-post3.jpg" alt="10 мест, ради которых стоит
  проснуться на рассвете">
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <div class="tags">
          <span class="tag">Music</span>
        </div>
        <div class="block-title">
          <h1>Лучшие музыкальные фестивали этого лета</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="date">
          <span>10 июня 2019</span>
        </div>
        <div class="author">
          <span>Неизвестный автор</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text-d">
          <p>Лето на носу, а с ним и музыкальные фестивали. На каком же из них вы разобьёте свою палатку?</p>
          <p>Мы составили список лучших летних фестивалей по всему миру.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article class="block">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="https://netology-code.github.io/html-2-diploma/sources/images/last-post4.jpg" alt="10 мест, ради которых стоит
  проснуться на рассвете">
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <div class="tags">
          <span class="tag">Lifestyle</span>
          <span class="tag">Food</span>
        </div>
        <div class="block-title">
          <h1>Наукоёмкий подход к кулинарии</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="date">
          <span>10 июня 2019</span>
        </div>
        <div class="author">
          <span>Неизвестный автор</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text-d">
          <p>Узнаем основы проектирования новых пищевых и около-пищевых опытов, вскроем физику, химию и микробиологию еды.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article class="block">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="https://netology-code.github.io/html-2-diploma/sources/images/last-post5.jpg" alt="10 мест, ради которых стоит
  проснуться на рассвете">
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <div class="tags">
          <span class="tag">Lifestyle</span>
          <span class="tag">Interior</span>
          <span class="tag">Art</span>
        </div>
        <div class="block-title">
          <h1>Делаем модные принты на подушках для интерьера </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="date">
          <span>10 июня 2019</span>
        </div>
        <div class="author">
          <span>Неизвестный автор</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text-d">
          <p>Подушки для дивана целесообразнее заказать в съемных чехлах на молнии, если потребуется чистка подушек, проще снять чехлы, чем везти подушку в химчистку.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article class="block">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="https://netology-code.github.io/html-2-diploma/sources/images/last-post6.jpg" alt="10 мест, ради которых стоит
  проснуться на рассвете">
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <div class="tags">
          <span class="tag">Travel</span>
          <span class="tag">Lifestyle</span>
        </div>
        <div class="block-title">
          <h1>Как первый раз отправиться в горы?</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="date">
          <span>10 июня 2019</span>
        </div>
        <div class="author">
          <span>Неизвестный автор</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text-d">
          <p>Для начала нужно определиться, в каком формате пройдёт ваше путешествие. Это зависит от многих факторов, не только от ваших желаний и интересов.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article class="block">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="https://netology-code.github.io/html-2-diploma/sources/images/last-post4.jpg" alt="10 мест, ради которых стоит
  проснуться на рассвете">
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <div class="tags">
          <span class="tag">Lifestyle</span>
          <span class="tag">Food</span>
        </div>
        <div class="block-title">
          <h1>Наукоёмкий подход к кулинарии</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="date">
          <span>10 июня 2019</span>
        </div>
        <div class="author">
          <span>Неизвестный автор</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text-d">
          <p>Узнаем основы проектирования новых пищевых и около-пищевых опытов, вскроем физику, химию и микробиологию еды.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

просто превратите `.block` во `flex`

```
.block {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 59px;
  width: 778px;
  
}
```

а у `.text` уберите правый `padding` и установите левый `margin`:

```
.text {
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

ну и дальше визуализацию уже подстройте как вам удобнее

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;700&display=swap');

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  margin: 0px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}

ul {
    padding-left: 0px;
    display: flex;
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 35px;
}

.menu {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-top: 28px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.header {
    display: flex;
}

.container {
    
    width: 1170px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}

.logo {
    width: 179px;
    height: 41px;
    margin-top: 28px
}

/* Интро */

.intro {
    display: block;
  padding-bottom: 120px;
    background-image: url(https://netology-code.github.io/html-2-diploma/sources/images/banner-bg.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
  margin-bottom: 64px;
}

.title {
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 45px;
  padding-left: 200px;
  padding-right: 200px;
  
}

.date {
  opacity: 50%;
}

.author {
  font-weight: 700;
}

.img {
 display: block;
 width: 381px;
}

.tag {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #b59f5b;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-right: 19px;
}

.block {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 59px;
  width: 778px;
  
}

.block-title {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.text {
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Контейнер --->
<div class="intro">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Хэдер -->
        <header>
            <div class="header">
                <div class="logo">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="https://netology-code.github.io/html-2-diploma/sources/images/noemi-logo.svg">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <nav class="menu">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Главная</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Посты</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Статьи</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Теги</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Темы</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Контакты</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="title">
                <h3>Блог о творчестве, спорте, и образе жизни</h3>
            </div>  
        </header>
    </div>
</div>
<main>
  <div class="container">
    <article class="block">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="https://netology-code.github.io/html-2-diploma/sources/images/last-post1.jpg" alt="10 мест, ради которых стоит
  проснуться на рассвете">
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <div class="tags">
          <span class="tag">Health</span>
          <span class="tag">Travel</span>
        </div>
        <div class="block-title">
          <h1>10 мест, ради которых стоит проснуться на рассвете</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="date">
          <span>10 июня 2019</span>
        </div>
        <div class="author">
          <span>Неизвестный автор</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text-d">
          <p>Итак, вы в Питере. Раннее утро. Лед с рек и каналов уже ушел, запущены фонтаны города… Музеи еще закрыты. Что посмотреть?</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article class="block">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="https://netology-code.github.io/html-2-diploma/sources/images/last-post2.jpg" alt="10 мест, ради которых стоит
  проснуться на рассвете">
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <div class="tags">
          <span class="tag">Health</span>
          <span class="tag">Lifestyle</span>
        </div>
        <div class="block-title">
          <h1>ЙОга для начинающих в домашних условиях</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="date">
          <span>10 июня 2019</span>
        </div>
        <div class="author">
          <span>Неизвестный автор</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text-d">
          <p>Расскажем, какие упражнения выбрать и как сделать коврик для занятий йогой из того, что можно найти в шкафу.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article class="block">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="https://netology-code.github.io/html-2-diploma/sources/images/last-post3.jpg" alt="10 мест, ради которых стоит
  проснуться на рассвете">
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <div class="tags">
          <span class="tag">Music</span>
        </div>
        <div class="block-title">
          <h1>Лучшие музыкальные фестивали этого лета</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="date">
          <span>10 июня 2019</span>
        </div>
        <div class="author">
          <span>Неизвестный автор</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text-d">
          <p>Лето на носу, а с ним и музыкальные фестивали. На каком же из них вы разобьёте свою палатку?</p>
          <p>Мы составили список лучших летних фестивалей по всему миру.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article class="block">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="https://netology-code.github.io/html-2-diploma/sources/images/last-post4.jpg" alt="10 мест, ради которых стоит
  проснуться на рассвете">
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <div class="tags">
          <span class="tag">Lifestyle</span>
          <span class="tag">Food</span>
        </div>
        <div class="block-title">
          <h1>Наукоёмкий подход к кулинарии</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="date">
          <span>10 июня 2019</span>
        </div>
        <div class="author">
          <span>Неизвестный автор</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text-d">
          <p>Узнаем основы проектирования новых пищевых и около-пищевых опытов, вскроем физику, химию и микробиологию еды.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article class="block">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="https://netology-code.github.io/html-2-diploma/sources/images/last-post5.jpg" alt="10 мест, ради которых стоит
  проснуться на рассвете">
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <div class="tags">
          <span class="tag">Lifestyle</span>
          <span class="tag">Interior</span>
          <span class="tag">Art</span>
        </div>
        <div class="block-title">
          <h1>Делаем модные принты на подушках для интерьера </h1>
        </div>
        <div class="date">
          <span>10 июня 2019</span>
        </div>
        <div class="author">
          <span>Неизвестный автор</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text-d">
          <p>Подушки для дивана целесообразнее заказать в съемных чехлах на молнии, если потребуется чистка подушек, проще снять чехлы, чем везти подушку в химчистку.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article class="block">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="https://netology-code.github.io/html-2-diploma/sources/images/last-post6.jpg" alt="10 мест, ради которых стоит
  проснуться на рассвете">
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <div class="tags">
          <span class="tag">Travel</span>
          <span class="tag">Lifestyle</span>
        </div>
        <div class="block-title">
          <h1>Как первый раз отправиться в горы?</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="date">
          <span>10 июня 2019</span>
        </div>
        <div class="author">
          <span>Неизвестный автор</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text-d">
          <p>Для начала нужно определиться, в каком формате пройдёт ваше путешествие. Это зависит от многих факторов, не только от ваших желаний и интересов.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article class="block">
      <div class="img">
        <img src="https://netology-code.github.io/html-2-diploma/sources/images/last-post4.jpg" alt="10 мест, ради которых стоит
  проснуться на рассвете">
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        <div class="tags">
          <span class="tag">Lifestyle</span>
          <span class="tag">Food</span>
        </div>
        <div class="block-title">
          <h1>Наукоёмкий подход к кулинарии</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="date">
          <span>10 июня 2019</span>
        </div>
        <div class="author">
          <span>Неизвестный автор</span>
        </div>
        <div class="text-d">
          <p>Узнаем основы проектирования новых пищевых и около-пищевых опытов, вскроем физику, химию и микробиологию еды.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </article>
  </div>
</main>
```